# Snowflake interprets boolean values in parquet as NULL?

Tags: apache-spark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, parquet, snowflake-schema, delta-lake

Parquet Entry Example (All entries have `is_active_entity` as true)

```
{
 "is_active_entity": true,
  "is_removed": false
}
```

Query that demonstrates all values are taken as NULL

```
select  $1:IS_ACTIVE_ENTITY::boolean, count(*) from @practitioner_delta_stage/part-00000-49224c02-150b-493b-8036-54ab30a8ff40-c000.snappy.parquet group by $1:IS_ACTIVE_ENTITY::boolean ;
```

**Output has only one group for NULL**

```
$1:IS_ACTIVE_ENTITY::BOOLEAN    COUNT(*)
    NULL                                            4930277
```

I don't know where I am going wrong, Spark writes the correct schema in parquet as evident from the example but snowflake takes it as NULL.

How do I fix this?

Comment: attributes of semi-structured data are case-sensitive in Snowflake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The columns in your file are quoted. As a consequence `"is_active_entity"` is not the same like `"IS_ACTIVE_ENTITY"`

Please try this query:

`select  $1:is_active_entity::boolean, count(*) from @practitioner_delta_stage/part-00000-49224c02-150b-493b-8036-54ab30a8ff40-c000.snappy.parquet group by $1:IS_ACTIVE_ENTITY::boolean ;`

More infos: [https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifiers-syntax.html#:~:text=The%20identifier%20is%20case%2Dsensitive](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifiers-syntax.html#:%7E:text=The%20identifier%20is%20case%2Dsensitive).